# How to delete a row if it shares the value of another row in one column and has one value in other column in R?

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a the following dataframe, let's call it Servers.

`Server <-c("AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRALIA", "AUSTRALIA","CHINA","COLOMBIA","COLOMBIA","ECUADOR","ECUADOR","ECUADOR","COREA","COREA","COREA","COREA","BRASIL","BRASIL","BRASIL","ALEMANIA","ALEMANIA","ALEMANIA","ALEMANIA")
Product <- c("021-08183","79P-01747","C5E-00746","7NQ-00302","7JQ-00341","021-08183","021-08183","79P-01747","79P-01747","021-08183","6QH-00002","79P-01747","021-08183","#N/A","6QH-00002","79P-01747","76P-00742","021-08183","021-08183","79P-01747","C5E-00746","7NQ-00302")
Servers <- data.frame(Server, Product)`

It looks like this

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j0tB.png)

What I need is the following. Whenever I have the same value in Server, and the values 021-08183 and 79P-01747, I need to remove the line that has the 021-08183 value, and keep only the one that has 79P-01747.

Output:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

PS: Sorry, I had some issues uploading the image for the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` package -

```
Servers %>% 
  group_by(Server) %>% 
  filter(
    (all(c("021-08183", "79P-01747") %in% Product) & (Product != "021-08183")) | n() == 1
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 2
   Server    Product  
   <chr>     <chr>    
 1 AUSTRALIA 79P-01747
 2 AUSTRALIA C5E-00746
 3 AUSTRALIA 7NQ-00302
 4 AUSTRALIA 7JQ-00341
 5 CHINA     021-08183
 6 COLOMBIA  79P-01747
 7 ECUADOR   79P-01747
 8 ECUADOR   6QH-00002
 9 COREA     79P-01747
10 COREA     #N/A     
11 COREA     6QH-00002
12 BRASIL    79P-01747
13 BRASIL    76P-00742
14 ALEMANIA  79P-01747
15 ALEMANIA  C5E-00746
16 ALEMANIA  7NQ-00302
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a logical condition after grouping by 'Servers', `filter` out the rows that have "021-08183" in the Product column when both ""021-08183", "79P-01747" are present in the column

```
library(dplyr)
Servers %>%
   group_by(Server) %>%
   filter(if(all(c("021-08183", "79P-01747") %in% Product)) 
     Product != "021-08183" else TRUE)
# A tibble: 16 x 2
# Groups:   Server [7]
#   Server    Product  
#   <fct>     <fct>    
# 1 AUSTRALIA 79P-01747
# 2 AUSTRALIA C5E-00746
# 3 AUSTRALIA 7NQ-00302
# 4 AUSTRALIA 7JQ-00341
# 5 CHINA     021-08183
# 6 COLOMBIA  79P-01747
# 7 ECUADOR   79P-01747
# 8 ECUADOR   6QH-00002
# 9 COREA     79P-01747
#10 COREA     #N/A     
#11 COREA     6QH-00002
#12 BRASIL    79P-01747
#13 BRASIL    76P-00742
#14 ALEMANIA  79P-01747
#15 ALEMANIA  C5E-00746
#16 ALEMANIA  7NQ-00302
```

---

Or a similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Servers)[, .SD[if(all(c("021-08183", "79P-01747") %in% Product)) 
        Product != "021-08183" else TRUE], Server]
```

NOTE: It gives the expected output as in the OP's post while keeping the row for 'CHINA'

Comment: For some reason I have been trying (but failing) to replicate, when I do it with the full dataframe I have, and I compare it to what I did initially in Excel, I do not get the same results. The dataframe has more columns, though they do not matter for me.
For example, I have other rows that have NA o empty values in the column "Product", but I guess that is not what generates the problem

Comment: @EliseoAvramides  It could be the NAs, if you can show a small reproducible example that generates the same problem, easy to figure out